# Wrapping a Windows Form Control within WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF45"
        xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Wordsearch_Editor.Models"
        xmlns:src="clr-namespace:Wordsearch_Editor"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:WpfRichText;assembly=WpfRichText" 
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser;assembly=AxSHDocVw.AxWebBrowser"
        xmlns:resc="clr-namespace:Wordsearch_WYSIWYG_Editor.Resources"
        x:Name="window"
        Title="Wordsearch Editor" Height="500" Width="815" MinHeight="500" MinWidth="850">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <wf:AxWebBrowser x:Name="mtbDate" Mask="00/00/0000"/>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
```

I have made references to both the AxWebBrowser and windows forms but for some reason I can't wrap the Windows Form control within WPF.

Comment: What does "I can't wrap" mean exactly? Any error or misbehavior?

Comment: Is there any chance that you could actually tell us what actual problem you're having? That code looks alright.

Comment: The namespace isn't correct. The AxWebrbowser control doesn't exist it says.

Comment: Then use the right namespace.

Comment: AxWebBrowser is not WinForms, is it? I think that's a native ActiveX.

Comment: So how should the XAML look?

Comment: Use VS object browser to get the right namespace. I doubt that it includes `AxWebBrowser`. But why don't you use WPF WebBrowser in the first place?